# Get Global Var Hardhat Console

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

Hi I am trying to test my contract in hardhat console. I am able to run my functions just fine but when I try to read a public global var it throws an error.

So for example:

```
    uint256 public testVar;

   function setInt(uint256 _intset) external {
        testVar = _intset;
    }
```

Then after successfully runnign await factory.setInt(123) in the console I run:

await factory.testVar()

But then for some reason I get the error message:

```
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="testVar()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.3)
    at step  {
  reason: null,
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  method: 'testVar()',
  data: '0x',
  errorArgs: null,
  errorName: null,
  errorSignature: null,
  address: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
  args: [],
  transaction: {
    data: '0x9c328fb3',
    to: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
    from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
    gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "29021272" }
  }
}
```

Any idea why i cannot simply get this public var?

Worth noting if i try run

await factory.testVar without the param it just says

[Function (anonymous)]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone in the future who is reading this. My problem was that in my hardhat config file I never configured my accounts:

So once I set:

```
accounts: [process.env.private_key]
```

It works fine.

WAGMI